# How to use javascript to validate form field?

Tags: javascript, html

Noob, trying to create a simple form, and validate the inputs on same. However, I don't know how to properly select each input in js, so nothing is happening. I am just learning html, bootstrap and javascript, so simpler (pythonic) answers are preferred to more complex ones.

I've read the documentation, and a number of other stackoverflow posts on this exact topic, which would have likely answered my question, were I not a Noob.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
        <small id="first_name_Help" class="form-text text-muted">* First Name is Mandatory.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
        <small id="last_name_Help" class="form-text text-muted">* Last Name is Mandatory.</small>
    </div>

    <p>Select Your Country of Residence Below</p>

    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="country">

            <option disabled selected value="">Country</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option></option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option></option>
            <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
            <option value="None of the Above">None of the Above</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>

    document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function() {
        if (!document.querySelector('input.first_name').value) {
            alert('You must provide your name!');
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Don't worry, you code looks fine, only there's a little problem in your js, `document.querySelector('input.first_name')` the dots `.` are used for classes just like in css, and hashtags `#` are used for id's. `first_name` is not a class nor a id, its a value inside the name attribute. For more references read [js selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong:

```
document.querySelector('input.first_name').value
```

You're selecting an `input` element with a "first_name" **class**. Your input class name is "form-control" and also it's not unique (which is fine). You must select using their `name` attributes. Like this:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=first_name]').value
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors#Selectors_article_overview

Answer (score 1):

You can validate a form with Javascript or as an alternative use the [built-in validation of HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Using_built-in_form_validation). In the snipppet below I'm using the "required" keyword to make an input field mandatory.

```css
input:invalid {
  border: solid red;
}

input:valid {
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
  <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required>
  <small id="first_name_Help" class="form-text text-muted">* First Name is Mandatory.</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
  <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" required>
  <small id="last_name_Help" class="form-text text-muted">* Last Name is Mandatory.</small>
</div>

<p>Select Your Country of Residence Below</p>

<div class="form-group">
  <select name="country">

    <option disabled selected value="">Country</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    </option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="None of the Above">None of the Above</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button>Submit</button>
```